# Casting in Spring Data specification org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I have the following entity structure:

```
                            | ParentObject|
                            +-------------+
                                   ^
                                   |
                           +-------+---------+----------------+
                           |                 |                |
                    +-----------+      +-----------+    +-----------+         
                    |   Son1   |       |  Son2     |    |   Son3    | 
                    +-----------+      +-----------+    +-----------+
```

What I want is to get all the Son2 and Son3 that have an attribute that doesn't exist on Son1

What I did so far:

```
class ParentObjectPredicat

public static Specification<ParentObject> inNaturesSon2(List<String> natures) {        
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        final Root<Son2> son2Root = cb.treat(root, Son2.class);
        return son2Root.get(Constants.NATURE).in(natures);
    }
}

public static Specification<ParentObject> inNaturesSon3(List<String> natures) {        
    return (root, query, cb) -> {
        final Root<Son3> son3Root = cb.treat(root, Son3.class);
        return son3Root.get(Constants.NATURE).in(natures);
    }
}

SpecSon2  son2Spec = ParentObjectPredicat.inNaturesSon2(natures);
SpecSon3  son3Spec = ParentObjectPredicat.inNaturesSon3(natures);

Specification<ParentObject> specifications = Specification.where(son2Spec).and(son3Spec);
Iterable<ParentObject> listOfSons = this.parentObjectRepository.findAll(specifications);
```

What I got as result:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [treat(null as mypackage.Son2).nature] of basic type; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal attempt to dereference path source [treat(null as mypackage.Son2).nature] of basic type

From my understanding `treat()` is used to resolve subclass. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I"m putting the answer of Petri Kainulainen for people who are maybe looking for the answser to this:

"Unfortunately you cannot write your query by using JPA because JPA doesn’t allow you to use attributes which aren’t found from all child classes if you want to “return” super class objects. As far as I know, you have two options:

You can invoke two queries which fetch Son2 and Son3 objects and combine the query results in Java code.
You can use SQL."